# Images not loading on chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a trouble with loading images on google chrome.

I am building a web site, i have built it in html.
When i run HTML file directly in browser it loads all files right away.

After splitting file into php files (to include header and footer and to load content on click) and moving to xampp for testing i have realized that images are not loading on google chrome every time.

I have tested HTML files via xampp, i get the same result, images are not loaded in chrome every time.

If i keep refreshing page, images load once, the next time some are loaded, some are not.

It works fine on Microsoft Edge and Mozilla Firefox.
Any solutions for this?

Comment: The PHP seems irrelevant if the HTML version does the same thing. What is the status code of the image requests when they fail?

Comment: can you share website address or a pice of your code?

Comment: I will post it here temporarly
http://trnic-gradnja.rs/test-website/

Comment: The images are loading, but the width is zero when the developer console is open in Chrome.

Comment: @Gerard what could be causing this and is there any solution to force widths to load?

It seems that when i refresh the page the images are loaded (probably because they are cached and the browser loads them as intended).

Comment: I have found what has been causing this problem: It was plugin that i used for grid layout. I have switched to collage grid and now its working fine. thanks for assist guys :)